# Joi array validation overrides the underlying errors. Is there a way to overcome this?

Tags: node.js, joi

I need to validate an array of objects. Each object could be either:

```
{
  id; "some-id"
}
```

or

```
{
  "mobile_number": "some-string"
}
```

I have the following code:

```
const Joi = require('Joi')


const idSchema = Joi.object().keys({
  user_id: Joi.string().required(),
});

const mobileSchema = Joi.object().keys({
  mobile_number: Joi.string().required().error(),
});

const schema = Joi.object()
    .keys({
      members: Joi.array()
      .items(idSchema, mobileSchema)
      .required()
    })
    .required()


console.log(Joi.validate({
  members: [{ mobile_number: null }],
}, schema))
```

I expect it show that the mobile_number is required. It fails with:

````
{ error: 
   { ValidationError: child "members" fails because ["members" at position 0 does not match any of the allowed types]```
````

The error that none of the items match the schema, overrides the underlying error.

Is there way around this?

Note: I am using Joi 10.6 and there are constraints around upgrading to the new version